# Keep image size when sharing image on Google Plus via Android

Tags: android, image, google-plus

I am working on an Android application where I wish to share an image via Google+. When I share an image using the code below, the image is posted on Google+, but the image is much smaller than the actual size; actual size is 640 x 480 and the image posted to Google+ is 288 x 216. What is the reason for this shrinkage in size and how can I fix this?

```
      File imageFile = new File(dir, System.currentTimeMillis() + ".jpg");      
      PlusShare.Builder share = new PlusShare.Builder(activity);
      share.addStream(Uri.fromFile(imageFile));
      share.setType("image/*");
      startActivityForResult(share.getIntent(), POST_REQ_GOOG);
```

Comment: Can you show the part where " imagefile" is set.?

Comment: I updated the question to show how the image file is set.